# Is there a way to kubectl apply all the files in a directory?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am writing an ansible playbook right now that deploys a dockerized application in kubernetes.  However, for molecularity purposes I would rather not hard code the files that need to be apply after doing `kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml --volumes hostPath`  Is there a way to apply all the files in a directory?

Comment: give the folder as a parameter but file names matter for apply order

Comment: would this be like: ```kubectl apply -f {{folder}}```?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can apply all files in a folder with

```
kubectl apply -f <folder>
```

You may also be interested in *parameterization* of your manifest files using [Kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/) e.g. use more replicas in a prod-namespace than in a test-namespace. You can apply parameterized manifest files with

```
kubectl apply -k <folder>
```

Comment: ...adding `--recursive` will recursively apply all files in subfolders too.

Comment: And `-R` is an alias for `--recursive` :)

Comment: And in practise, "kubectl apply -f  ." I just found "kompose". Brilliant, love it ;) -- Just browsed down the page: Greyman-Sacedo answered this already.

Answer (score 22):

The above command to give the directory as an option to "-f" works perfectly if you want to apply all the files in the given directory.

The following should apply the yaml files in the current directory matching the given criteria (e.g. here all yamls starting with test)

```
kubectl apply $(ls test*.yaml | awk ' { print " -f " $1 } ')
```

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me >> `kubectl apply -f .`

Answer (score 6):

An ansible-specific answer, using the ansible `k8s` module, would be:

```
      - name: Apply all manifests in a given folder
        k8s:
          state: present
          definition: "{{ lookup('template', '{{ item }}') }}"
          namespace: default
        with_fileglob:
          - "manifests/*.yaml"
          - "manifests/*.j2"
```

This would also allow you to template your manifests and parse them on-the-fly when applying the whole folder.

Please note that this ansible task expects that the `manifests` folder is in the same path as the running playbook is.

Answer (score 0):

Move to the folder where all the yaml files are present.

Now run `kubectl apply -f .`

Remember to specify `.` dot after the -f flag