# Kubernetes apply all files inside a directory, "kubectl apply --all"?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Just wondering, let's say I have X Kubernetes `deployment.yaml`, `pod.yaml`, `persistedvolumecliam.yaml` and `service.yaml` files inside a directory.

The tutorials would tell us to do the following:

```
kubectl apply -f frontend-service.yaml,redis-master-service.yaml,redis-slave-service.yaml,frontend-deployment.yaml,redis-master-deployment.yaml,redis-slave-deployment.yaml
```

Is there a way just to do something like:

```
kubectl apply all
```

or

```
kubectl apply -f *
```

or some variation thereof to spin all of the kube stuffs within on directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to kubectl apply all the files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491324/is-there-a-way-to-kubectl-apply-all-the-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can apply everything inside a directory with `kubectl apply -f /path/to/dir`. To include subdirectories use the paramter `-R`, like `kubectl apply -R -f /path/to/dir`

Answer (score 4):

```
# Apply resources from a directory
kubectl apply -f dir/

# Process the directory used in -f recursively
kubectl apply -R -f dir/
```

For more details check the [reference documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#apply).

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a YAML file using kubectl apply recursively in all folders by using the --recursive flag.

Here is the basic syntax once you are in the root folder:

```
kubectl apply --recursive -f .
```