# Iterate similar command over multiple items

Tags: shell, kubernetes, kubectl

If I'm trying to do a command like `kubectl apply -f dir1/subdir1/deployment.yml`, and I have `subdir1`, `subdir2`, etc, how can I run that command for all of them at once?

I tried `kubectl apply -f dir1/*/deployment.yml` and that passes all the `deployment.yml` to the single `-f` flag, making it invalid as that flag accepts a single argument.

I've also tried `kubectl apply -f dir1/{subdir1,subdir2}/deployment.yml` with no luck.

PS: I'm using zsh for my shell with oh-my-zsh+p10k if that matters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to kubectl apply all the files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491324/is-there-a-way-to-kubectl-apply-every-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

A command-agnostic solution in `zsh`:

```
for d (dir1/*/deployment.yml) kubectl apply -f "$d"
```

This uses a `zsh`-specific alternate form of the `for` loop, more commonly written as

```
for d in dir1/*/deployment.yml; do kubectl apply -f "$d"; done
```

(Though this is admittedly different from running `kubectl` precisely once and letting *it* iterate over the configurations itself.)

Answer (score 0):

To include subdirectories use the parameter -R, like

`kubectl apply -R -f /path/to/dir`

Where -R is the parameter used for **Processing the directory used in -f recursively**

Refer this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#apply) for more information on kubectl apply command.